# Ribbon Contextual Menu In Excel 2021

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create context menus that are grayed out under certain conditions and the GetEnabled="IsNotTopAssemblySheet" causes the problem. If I take it out the menu works, but is always available. Any one have an example of context menus for Excel that can be grayed out when on a certain sheet name, etc. TIA.

I have this XML loaded via RibbonX editor:

```
<customUI onLoad="OnLoad" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
   <contextMenus>
      <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuCell">
         <button id="btnGoToTopAssembly" 
                 label="Go To Top Assembly" 
                 onAction="GoToTopAssembly" 
                 getEnabled="IsNotTopAssemblySheet"
                 insertBeforeMso="Cut"/>
      </contextMenu>
   </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

And this call in vba module.

```
Public MyRibbon As IRibbonUI

Sub OnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set MyRibbon = ribbon
End Sub

Public Function IsNotTopAssemblySheet(control As IRibbonControl) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    If Application.ActiveSheet.Name = "Top Assembly" Then
        IsNotTopAssemblySheet = False
    Else
        IsNotTopAssemblySheet = True
    End If
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    IsNotTopAssemblySheet = True ' Default to True on error
End Function


Sub GoToTopAssembly(control As IRibbonControl)
    MsgBox "Go To Top Assembly clicked!"
End Sub
```

I get this error when right clicking in the excel sheet:

Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following VBA callback for IsNotTopAssemblySheet instead...

```
Sub IsNotTopAssemblySheet(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    If Application.ActiveSheet.Name = "Top Assembly" Then
        returnedVal = False
    Else
        returnedVal = True
    End If
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    returnedVal = True ' Default to True on error
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much it appears to have worked! As I work some more I will report back.

Comment: You're very welcome, cheers!